# how to change temp files from cycles render to be handled on another disk drive?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, performance, path, file-browser

I have a small C system with 14 gb left but three more disks with over 300 free space each, and yet when i render with cycles the space for the files to render is taken from the main C drive, how can i change this? there's also the file paths in preferences and those do not change anything

see?
[image]
[image]
[image]